# Ubuntu 18.05/20.04 freezes!

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

I am using an HP-ProBook-450-G7 (Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80 GHz × 8) with Intel® UHD Graphics (CML GT2). I previously had Ubuntu 20.04 installed which worked just fine for a couple of weeks.

Then I started facing problems like frequent freeze while working and even on bootup. I re-installed Ubuntu thinking maybe an issue with previous installed but started getting the same issues after a couple of weeks.

I shifted back to Ubuntu 18.05 thinking maybe the build of Ubuntu 20 is not matured yet but still getting the same issues. I am thinking to move back to windows as I am a developer cant install all of my tools every 3rd week for a new OS.

I thought to give Ubuntu a last shot can someone point out any possible reason for the crashes?

Comment: Do you see anything of note in the contents of `/var/log` from around the time of the freeze? Perhaps `kern.log`, `kern.log.1`, and `syslog` would be of help? Additionally, does the computer still respond on a network while frozen (`ping`, `ssh`)?

Comment: I haven't checked the logs, and the computer freezes up totally I cant do anything other than force restart

Answer (score 0):

You should just remove `xserver-xorg-video-intel`.
had the same issue with almost the same model, I've `i5`, and followed up this link(was searching about two weeks for the solution)
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1798961/comments/83
I think in the beginning I hadn't these drivers installed, it was just my searching of improvements and setting up env.
since I followed this recomendation there is no one freeze at all.
thanks to all for voting for delete my answer

Comment: Had the same isue for several weeks, random even reisub didn't work

Comment: Would you mind explaining how to remove, why will it solve the issue, and why and how will the system work after having removed an apparently important part from it? Maybe a link to a resource that supports this position?

Comment: yeah, sure @Levente, I've added link. simply `sudo apt remove`

Comment: still don't freezes with me, so this solution works